# Docker compose failing in windows 10

Tags: docker-compose

I am on docker for windows version 2.3.0.5 and my docker compose is failing with this stranger error :

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
File "compose\cli\main.py", line 78, in main
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str
[25608] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Comment: Please post your `docker-compose.yml` and your `main.py`

Comment: I had the same problem, but for me the problem was the Dockerfile with the wrong name

Answer (score 10):

For me, it was because docker-compose wasn't able to find a referenced Dockerfile. This happened after renaming one of the projects (thus changing its folder's name).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your help, it turned out to be a windows issue with docker which is a nightmare.
So I have restarted Docker and it works.

Comment: I have the same issue with the same error line and I restarted the docker but no changes !! so can you guide me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case this turned out to be a lack of resources allocated to Docker so I had to go to docker dashboard and increase memory and cpu allocated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `dockerfile: .` in docker-compose file, it would probably give the error mentioned above.

To avoid this error explicitly specify the dockerfile name as `dockerfile: Dockerfile`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it turns out that I still had venv enables. Once I got out (deactivate) it worked perfectly.

Comment: A short explanation on how you disabled venv would be nice :)

Comment: If you are in the venv (you see this if 'venv' is written in your command line on the left) you just write the command 'deactivate' and then the 'venv' on your left should be gone. This then means you left it. I hope this helps!